# Order of Figure in a Review Copy article

Tags: floats, sorting

Order of figures (floats) is a common issue with LaTeX.

I'm using a LaTeX template from a journal editor in my  article I will submit for peer-review. I cannot thus use any of my own packages or anything else which is provided by the `cls` file.

The journal editing policy ask author to put figures at the very end of the article. So I move my figure's environments at the end and use `\label` and `\ref` in order to call them.

The thing is that my figure are not sorted in the `.tex` file as they are called. This means that for instance if fig2 is called in the text before fig1 the number of fig2 will be 2 and not 1 in the compiled version. This is really annoying, LaTeX should take into account the calling order and Not the order the `\begin{figure}` command in the `.tex`, because this does not make sense to me, what is the advantage in that case to use `\ref` and `\label`, I should hard code directly the number of each figure myself. So I'm sure I'm missing something.

Any feedback would appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: You can try with the `endfloat` package

Comment: @Guido, unfortunately the OP wrote "I cannot thus use any of my own packages or anything else which is [sic] provided by the `cls` files."

Comment: In general authors want figures to be numbered in the order they appear, and this is what `LaTeX` (usually) does. Do you really want to number them in the order they are referenced?

Comment: yes but here I am in a very specific situation for which I wish the figures sorted as they are called in the text. This is why I'm posting here. thanks.

Comment: I think this is likely to be more trouble than it is worth (i.e. nothing). Does the journal require you to do this?

Answer (score 1):

you can probably do the job by

(a) add `endfloat` to your paper as you develop it
(b) when you're done, edit out `endfloat`, and edit the `.fff` file from `endfloat` in at the end of the file